# initialize an array of structs inside another struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm completely stumped.  How do I fill a `struct` array that is contained inside another `struct`?

I have the two `struct`s:

```
struct employee_stats{
    char emp_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    double salary;
    int years_employed;
}

struct annual_reviews{
    int year;
    struct employee_stats employee[NO_EMPLOYEES];
}
```

I declare a pointer to an array of `annual_reviews` structs

```
annual_reviews *sort_records = new annual_reviews[num_years];
```

I have a `vector` of strings that read from a text file earlier in the program. I send the `employee_record` and `year` vectors to a method to fill the two `struct`s

```
void DataSort::load_records(vector<string> employee_record, vector<string> year){
    vector<string> line_data;
    string word;

    //split employee_record by \t and into single line string vector
    for(int i = 0; i < employee_record.size(); i++){
         stringstream wordstream(employee_records[i]);
         while(getline(wordstream, word, '\t')){
             if(!word.empty())
                 line.push_back(word);
         }
    }
```

Now , within the same method, I want to add this data to my `struct`s:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < num_years; j++){
        sort_records[i].year = atoi(year[i].c_str); //year of record
        for(int k = 0; k < NO_EMPLOYEES; k++){
            //here is where it all falls apart
            sort_records[j].employee_stats[j].emp_name = line[j]; //fill the records
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I'm not accessing the inside `struct` correctly but I'm stuck, I've hit a wall.

I get two compilation errors using VS2015:

```
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str':non-standard syntax;use'&'to create a pointer to member

array type 'char[25]' is not assignable
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Do I need to create a pointer to the member `struct`?  I thought you could index the members directly.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why your number of employees is hard coded?

Comment: Fixed.  The number of employees is static in this case.

Comment: I would make `emp_name` an `std::string` and the `employee_stats` member an `std::vector<employee_stats>`

Comment: I would too, however I can't change any aspect of the two structs.  I just have to deal with them as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

struct used for making datatype.

```
struct employee_stats{
    char emp_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    double salary;
    int years_employed;
}

struct annual_reviews{
    int year;
    struct employee_stats[NO_EMPLOYEES];
}
```

on the annual_reviews datatype, i think you declare another datatype by using

```
struct employee_stats
```

so i think you should declare it as a data array as you want it on the second one

```
struct employee_stats{
    char emp_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    double salary;
    int years_employed;
}

struct annual_reviews{
    int year;
    employee_stats employeeData[NO_EMPLOYEEs];
}
```

Here after making variable type annual_reviews, i think you can access the employeeData array. And then for the char error, i think you should use string as dataType on emp_name.

[EDIT]
copy string to char

```
strcpy(sort_records[j].employee_stats[j].emp_name, line[j].c_str());
```

Reading source : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: Edited:  Added employee variable of employee_stats type.  I had inadvertently left it out of my post, it is in the code I'm trying to compile though.  Not working as written above.

Comment: if you cant change struct into string, for char problem use string class function c_str. Added to edit.

Comment: I'm getting the same compilation error:  std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str':non-standard syntax;use'&'to create a pointer to member

Comment: is it come from strcpy line? or another line?

Comment: From the strcpy line

Comment: The only thing come to my mind is your compiler think that you want to add char to a pointer. But if you already declare it as a variable, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: changed c_str to c_str().  Compiles fine.  Lets see if my logic works now!  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are not declaring the inner structure correctly.

You code should look like some thing like this (pseudo-code):

```
typedef employee_stats some_type;
Use some_type inside annual_reviews.
```

The rest is trivial.

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't I need a pointer to the container object?  So typedef struct annual_reviews *reviewPointer.  Then I could access the members of the object the *reviewPointer is pointing to?  reviewPointer->employee->emp_name..

Comment: @corporateWhore, as I wrote that was a pseudo-code. It should give you an idea of what to do. The actual implementation is up to you.